# jquery ajax refuses to send POST request. Always send GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I am have a problem with jQuery ajax NOT sending POST requests. every question and answer I've looked at doesn't help.

I'm using Laravel 5.4 so jQuery is built into app.js and I know it's not a problem with jQuery as I can perform similar ajax requests doing POST and they worked perfectly fine.

Here is the code in question

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Save &amp; Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('#btn-save').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/account-reset/qr-code/store",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: 'some-long-value',
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('.row').last().hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the save button, the console sends a GET request to /account-reset which is not what I specified.

If I add a trailing slash to the end of the url, it calls the correct url but it still sends a GET request so Laravel returns a 405 error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Why will ajax not do a POST request like I'm telling it to?

**UPDATE**
Here is my routes. You can see that's I'm using a POST request. There is no difference (except controllers) with a route that works as it should

```
Route::prefix('account-reset')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/qr-code/{id}', 'ResetController@qrcode')->name('reset.qrcode.save');
    Route::post('/qr-code/store', 'ResetController@qrcode_store')->name('reset.qrcode.store');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that in your routes you have post method?

Comment: Isnt it method post not type?

Comment: Can you please show your routes file?

Comment: Both are valid @BobVale

Comment: I think you are mistaken.

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you have defined your route as something other than POST. `Route::post('/account-reset/qr-code/store', 'Your\Namespace\Controller@postMethod);` <- is what that route definition should look like. Make sure you haven't defined it as `Route::get(...)`.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly valid question. Please post a comment to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console and check the post request variable. If your request is sending variable in post tab then you should check your routes.

Do you have another routes like resource('account-reset/qr-code','YourController') or like get('account-reset/qr-code/{variable}','YourController')?

Sometimes if you have another route like above, laravel stops in this first route.

I think, you should change the name of route and keep it unique and then try.

I hope the problem will get resolved.

Comment: Why downvoted? Route conflicts may be the reason for this error, as we do not know the route definition.